# Troubleshooting Newsstand ATOM feed

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store-connect, atom-feed, newsstand-kit

I'm currently working on a magazine app compatible with iOS Newsstand feature. I've set everything up and the only thing left is the ATOM feed which should automatically update current issue on the App Store.

But here's the problem. I've linked iTunes Connect to the feed and nothing happens. The form undergoes the initial validation (so the schema appears validated). However, once the feed information is saved, I don't see any progress (I'm doing this for the first time but I suppose that even in "prepare for upload" state I should see some issues popping up).

I know Apple retrieves the feed on a daily basis, a rather slower interval to test hypotheses. But it's in there for few days now and I don't have any idea what went wrong.

Here's the URL of my feed: http://easymagazine.cz/api/1/atomfeed/issues

Feel free to examine the feed and point out any deviations from the Apple specification which can be found here: https://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/NewsstandAtomFeedSpecification.pdf.

Thanks in advance.
PM

Comment: I haven't done a Newsstand app, but based on the WWDC videos it seems if you use an XML atom feed then iTunes doesn't actually have a lot to do with it. I would check out WWDC2011 session 504 & WWDC2012 session 307. Also, in the video they say the once a day throttling can be de-activated by setting `NKDontThrottleNewstandContentnotifications` to `YES` in the `NSUserDefaults`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check those sessions out. However, I think there may be a misunderstanding. This has nothing to do with my app bundle, `NKDontThrottleNewstandContentnotifications` applies to the Newsstand push notifications in the bundle. I'm trying to correctly set up Newsstand in the iTunes Connect (it should automatically update my app profile on the App Store based on the latest issue).

Comment: Brother, I am facing the same issue. Can you help me out?

Comment: I didn't manage to figure it out before the app went public. So, I took a shot and turned out, iTunes Connect started to update the data once the app got the "Ready for Sale" status. So, if you are in a similar situation, just check your feed for any potential problems and when you're satisfied, release your app - it should work.